# change indexing of array in c

Tags: arrays, c

I am stuck in the problem of an array. I want to print something like this in C language.

input= arr[14]={2,0,2,2,0,1,1,4,0,4,2,2,3,3};

output I need is: output=arr2[6]={2022,01,14,04,22,33};

is this possible in the c language. your help will be very appreciated. thanks

Comment: `arr2[0] = arr[0]*1000 + arr[1]*100 + arr[2]*10 + arr[3]; arr2[1] = arr[4]*10 + arr[5]; ...`

Comment: Thank you so much sir it really save a lot of my time. Can you please complete the series? thanks @pm

Comment: Nope, you can easily complete the series. **Learning** or programming **by copy/paste is not good learning**.

Comment: Okay sir thank you so much.

Comment: It sounds as what you really want is to convert raw decimal digits to a string, for pretty printing purposes...?

Comment: Yes sir. but I have successfully implemented it. special thanks to @pmg

Answer (score 0):

`arr2[0] = arr[0]*1000 + arr[1]*100 + arr[2]*10 + arr[3]; arr2[1] = arr[4]*10 + arr[5]; ...`

or, if you really really want to make a function

```
#include <stdio.h>

void mix2(int *a, int *b, int alen) {
    for (int i = 0; i < alen; i++) {
        a[i] = b[2*i]*10 + b[2*i+1];
    }
}

int main(void) {
    int arr[14] = {2, 0, 2, 2, 0, 1, 1, 4, 0, 4, 2, 2, 3, 3};
    int arr2[6];

    mix2(arr2, arr + 2, 6);              // 22, 01, 14, 04, 22, 33 into arr2
    arr2[0] += arr[0]*1000 + arr[1]*100; // add missing terms

    printf("arr2:");
    for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++) printf(" %d", arr2[i]);
    printf("\n");

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thank You so much, sir, I am trying to implement it in my code as my code is thousands of lines. thanks